# Sequence number, incorrect number

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mariadb

In a spring boot application, I have this entity

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="user_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="user_id_seq",sequenceName="user_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
Long id
 ...
```

}

In mariadb, when I check the sequence

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE `user_id_seq` start with 1 minvalue 1 maxvalue 9223372036854775806 increment by 1 cache 1000 nocycle ENGINE=InnoDB
```

In db, I have only 5 user.

```
select id from `user` u
```

This query return

1002
1004
1005
2007
3001

Why it's not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Is it beaucause of the cache 1000?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its because of the cache. The numbers in the cache are thrown away on shutdown or even table cache closing the sequence.

If there isn't a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org) already, please create one. Its a rather easy fix to save a single number on closing the table.